# Any good web service used for SMS integration in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sms, sms-gateway

Is there any good web service used for SMS integration in mvc4?
     I know about ozeki but it can't be used as webservice for SMS in mvc4 but there are other list of available webservice like smsgateway etc which makes me confused to choose ,any idea which can be used.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard good things about [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com)

Comment: Twillo can be used as the webservice without connecting it to modem

Comment: Now i used this one. you too try http://smsgatewaycenter.com

Comment: @AngDei Is smsgatewaydenter a good one